# Sandbox testing & Redirection Issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

For testing my adaptive api payments with new sandbox (Developer.Paypal.com) i have imported my sandbox accounts into the live paypal account. But on testing the payment i am not getting redirect to the PayPal Store page. Instead it asks me to login into http://developer.paypal.com on which i am already login. Even when i does login it do not show me the store page for the payment but instead just show me the homepage for the developer site.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=PA-30G61643G7253031W

Above is the URL which i got as result of testing for payment from my site along with the approval key. But i am just moving in the circles of this new paypal transition. As i have also tried deleting my cookies on the Mozila. I am using iMac.

Same happens when i try to go to sandbox site from inside the live account, it sends me to the sandbox site where i get message to login into the developer.paypal site

Please advise how to get rid of these PayPal bugs for testing the Workflow which earlier was working smoothly untill PayPal decided to roll out new changes (Required Live account for testing).

Looking for guidance on this issue.

Comment: It looks like it's a cookie issue. I went ahead and logged into my developer account and was able to sign up for the Preapproval. You should be able to see my agreement in your test account. 

Could you try and deleting all cookies and cache, logging into the developer account and generate a new Preapproval key? If you continue to have errors let me know what browser is being used and I'll try testing under your same conditions.

Comment: Ok it worked for me. But clearing Cookies each time isn't a good solution. As often it also fails. And on refreshing the page or going back it gets login again.